# How to know remote server ip in jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, remote-server, build-triggers

I implemented jenkins build script.
That script started by remote server. ( using Build Triggers )

In build console Output log, wrote down

"Started by remote host xx.xx.xxx.xxx (my ip)"

I want to know remote host that called jenkins build job in pipeline script.

Any ideas??

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry i wrote wrong * remote host -> remote ip. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set an environment variable `BUILD_CAUSES`  in your Jenkins pipeline script. Which will save all build information
You can access it by jenkins file

```groovy
def remoteHost = ''
for (cause in currentBuild.getCauses()) {
    if (cause instanceof Cause.RemoteCause) {
        remoteHost = cause.getAddr()
        break
    }
}
println "Remote host IP: ${remoteHost}"
```

To set environment variable

- click on the job where you want to set the variable from homepage.
- Go to "Configure" link for your job.
- Go to "Build Environment" section.
- Check the "Set environment variables" checkbox.
- In the "Name" field, enter "BUILD_CAUSES".
- In the "Value" field, enter the desired value for the BUILD_CAUSES
  variable.
- Click the "Save" button to save your changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How to set BUILD_CAUSES ???